# sklearn using knn with user-specified metric and non-array data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I would like to do k-nearest neighbour learning data that is not given in a feature-vector format (in fact, 3D numpy arrays) using a custom (user-specified, via a function) function. I do this in sklearn. I have two questions:

a. What is the rationale behind KNeighborsClassifier insisting on 1D array data when using a custom metric?
b. When rolling a custom estimator that does not check the shape of the input arrays (as in http://scikit-learn.org/dev/developers/contributing.html#rolling-your-own-estimator) there are some incompatibilities when using nested cross validation. Where except in the .fit() routine of the estimator is the shape of X and y checked?

I do not provide code, as my main concern is to understand what is the design principle behind such a rigid input handling. I find it not very natural to do reshaping operations. I thank you very much for literature pointers.

Comment: If you have a 3D ndarray then you have a 3 feature vector for each sample. Right?

Comment: No, each feature "vector" is a 3D array, i.e. Indexed by three indices.

Answer (score 0):

It's standard to input each sample as a 1D array of the form `np.array([feature1, feature2, feature3, ...])`. Your training and testing data `X` should then look like this:

`np.array([[sample1_feature1, sample1_feature2, ...],
          [sample2_feature1, sample2_feature2, ...],
          ...])`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation: The input format I figured out. I was asking myself whether it is possible to have a working estimator that does not have this data format (and where it would crash). The reason I think that this particular data format is not necessary is that for a metric that is passed as a python function there should be no optimised C code in the back that works on feature vectors and therefore no reason for type checks. Or am I going wrong?

Comment: I'm still not sure how to answer your question. But from my perspective it makes sense to feed in flattened data because models can learn correlations between features regardless of how they are positioned within the matrix. Plus, like you are saying, it would take more computational effort to deal with samples not shaped like a 1D array.